# Is -u ever needed for pushing Git tags?

Tags: git, tags, push, bitbucket

Using Git the `--set-upstream` flag (or `-u`) for `git push` makes your local branch a tracking branch of the server; you only have to do this once, e.g.:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Afterwards you can simply do the following. (I know there are even shorter forms, but I'm just getting to my main question.)

```
git push origin master
```

Pushing a tag takes the same form, e.g. for the "v1.0" tag:

```
git push origin v1.0
```

But a tag (usually) stays pointing to a single commit; I don't see that there is anything to "track". So would there be any need to use `-u` when pushing a tag?

I see no mention of using -u with tags in [Pro Git, Second Edition](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). However the instruction page for [importing new repositories on Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/import-code-from-an-existing-project-259358821.html) clearly says to use `-u`:

```
git push -u origin --tags
```

Is this a typo on Bitbucket, or is there some purpose in specifying `-u` when pushing Git tags?

**Update:** Based upon the answer here, I filed an issue with Atlassian and they fixed the typo (as that what it apparently was). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git tag` does have a `-u` option. However it is supposed to be used to sign the tag with a given key rather than to push upstream.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag

It does seem to be an oversight on Bitbucket's part.

Comment: Thanks. I filed an issue with Atlassian and they fixed the typo.